# How to convert mm/dd/yy string to "Monday 7th Jan"

Tags: java, date, time, java-8, formatting

I have a database file with mm/dd/yy values for events, and I want to display the date as something similar to "Day(word), day(number), month(word)".

01/07/19 into
Monday 4th Jan or Monday 4 Jan or something similar.

Comment: @el-teedee: Please do not encourage the use of `SimpleDateFormat`, it is outdated and has been replaced with [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the string to date and then convert back to String like this :

```
     DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
     Date date = format1.parse("01-01-2019");
     DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
     String dateString = format2.format(date);
     System.out.println(dateString); //<- prints January 01, 2019
```

**How to use the SimpleDateFormat?**

Java provides a class called a SimpleDateFormat that allows you to format and parse dates in the as per your requirements.

You can use the above characters to specify the format - For example:

1) Date format required: `2019.01.01 20:20:45 PST`

The appropriate date format specified will be- `yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss zzz`

2) Date format required:`09:30:00 AM 01-Jan-2019`

The appropriate date format specified will be-`hh:mm:ss a dd-MMM-yyyy`

**Tip:** Be careful with the letter capitalization. If you mistake M with m, you will undesired results!

Let's learn this with a code example.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class TestDates_Format {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Date objDate = new Date(); // Current System Date and time is assigned to objDate
  System.out.println(objDate);
  String strDateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a dd-MMM-yyyy"; //Date format is Specified
  SimpleDateFormat objSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat); //Date format string is passed as an argument to the Date format object
  System.out.println(objSDF.format(objDate)); //Date formatting is applied to the current date
 }
}
```

Output :

```
Sat Mar 02 16:37:59 UTC 2019
04:37:59 PM 02-Mar-2019
```

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
LocalDate.of(2019, 3, 2).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd MMM YYYY"))
```